# Why does the result being so different

Tags: matlab-figure

I was new to Matlab,and this time I want to create a function for its image process.
Firstly, I download a picture from the Internet.Then I named it "map.jpg",and copy to my workspace.latter,I create a M_files and type the code into the files.
for example:

```
function y=mean_data(gray)
s=size(gray);
sum=0;
for i=1:s(1)
    for j=1:s(2)
        sum=sum+gray(i,j);
    end
end
y=sum/(s(1)*s(2));
```

Finally,the difference happenend:

if I call the function in this way:

```
I=imread('map.jpg');
J=rgb2gray(I);
mean=mean_data(double(J))
```

the result will be OK.

However if I call in this way:

```
I=imread('map.jpg');
J=rgb2gray(I);
mean=mean_data(J)
```

the result will be zero.

So why does the result being so different?And thank you for helping me!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase the default output format of the data read by `imread`
is `uint8` that is - 8 bit per R/G/B. With 8 bit you can't get any integer
higher than 255. Take a look:

```
>> uint8(250) + uint8(5)
ans =
255

>> uint8(250) + uint8(6)
ans =
255
```

So then, during division in your function this thing happens:

```
>> uint8(255) / 12345
ans =
0
```

However, when you use `double()` you change the representation of
your data to 64 bit floating point - a lot more room for representing big
numbers.

Instead of using your loop function you can use matlab's `mean`
function - it works well with uint8 format:

```
>> mean(uint8([255, 231]))
ans =
243
```

So you can use:

```
mean_dat = mean(mean(J));
% it is also not a good idea to name a variable 'mean'
% if you are going to use the mean function so I renamed  
% your variable to mean_dat
```